# Matplotlib x-labels vertical cut

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to generate a plot containing various labels arranged vertically by using this method:

```
def feat_imp(df, model, title, n_features, file_exp, format_exp):

d = dict(zip(df.columns, model.feature_importances_))
ss = sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
top_names = ss[0:n_features]

plt.figure()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.title(title)
plt.bar(range(n_features), [d[i] for i in top_names], color="g", align="center")
plt.xlim(-1, n_features)
plt.xticks(range(n_features), top_names, rotation='vertical')
plt.savefig(file_exp, format=format_exp, dpi=1200)
```

However, when doing so, the labels are not taken into account when matplotlib creates the EPS file (I need EPS):

[image]

This is how I call the def:

```
feat_imp(df_K562, model, "Feature importances (" + cell_name + " - " + model_name + " - TOP 30)", 30, root_path + dest_path + "TOP30.eps", "eps")
```

I have tried to activate ”autoSize” in the matplotlib config file, I have tried to put a specific dpi and also to set plt.tight_layout(). Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have edited the def like this, and it works:

```
def feat_imp(df, model, title, n_features, file_exp, format_exp):
d = dict(zip(df.columns, model.feature_importances_))
ss = sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)
top_names = ss[0:n_features]
plt.figure()
plt.title(title)
plt.bar(range(n_features), [d[i] for i in top_names], color="g", align="center")
plt.xlim(-1, n_features)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='minor', labelsize=6)
plt.xticks(range(n_features), top_names, rotation='vertical')
plt.autoscale()
plt.savefig(file_exp, format=format_exp, bbox_inches = "tight")
```